# Jquery desktop to Mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile

I developed a web application using jquery/html in front end and webservice (restful) in back end ,how to check the compatibilty of this site on mobile?

I googled and found something called jquery mobile,how can this help me?I mean can i use the same code (code for desktops) to mobile or  i need to develop code seperately,and also how to test the app.

Answer (score 0):

jquery mobile is an framework to build native like webapps.

it supports iphone transition animations and is multi browser compatible.

to test mobile apps -> check out these tools

http://speckyboy.com/2010/04/12/mobile-web-and-app-development-testing-and-emulation-tools/

http://www.genuitec.com/mobile/